# Adding a new column to a pandas dataframe with different number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, rows

I'm not sure if pandas is made to do this... But I'd like to add a new row to my dataframe with more rows than the existing columns.

Minimal example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['a'] = [0,1]
df ['b'] = [0,1,2]
```

Could someone please explain if this is possible? I'm using a dataframe to store long lists of data and they all have different lengths that I don't necessarily know at the start.

Comment: AFAIK it's not possible, because all columns must have the same length (same number of rows)

Comment: Ah no. That means I'll have to make separate dataframes or something for my longer data.... thanks hey.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Absolutely possible.  Use `pd.concat`

#### Demonstration

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

`df1` looks like

```
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
```

`df2` looks like

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5
0  4  5  6  7  8  9
```

`pd.concat` looks like

```
   0  1  2    3    4    5
0  1  2  3  NaN  NaN  NaN
0  4  5  6  7.0  8.0  9.0
```